# How to get the label of a choice in a Django forms ChoiceField?

Tags: python, django, choicefield

I have a `ChoiceField`, now how do I get the *label* when I need it?

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
     reason = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[("feature", "A feature"),
                                         ("order", "An order")],
                                widget=forms.RadioSelect)
```

`form.cleaned_data["reason"]` only gives me the `feature` or `order` *values* or so.

Comment: I think you may need to reconsider which answer is the accepted one..

Comment: @Dan: Why? Which one do you prefer?

Comment: @webjunkie The one with the most up-votes is the more django-centric one which requires less code be written on a per-model basis.

Comment: @JackM. if you mean @shacker's, it doesn't actually answer the question. `get_FOO_display` applies to `django.db.models.ChoiceField`, not `django.forms.ChoiceField`. The currently-accepted answer (by Andrés) is the best one can do as of Django 1.5, I believe.

Comment: The accepted answer also works in more cases. For example if you query the `FOO` table, but want a `dict` rather than a model (using `FOO.objects.values()`), it will work with tiny adjustments. @shacker's answer works only for full-fledged models.

Comment: Weird enough, Django considers in this example `feature` and `order` as values, and `A feature`, `An order` as labels. [Source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#enumeration-types)

Answer (score 98, accepted):

This may help:

```
reason = form.cleaned_data['reason']
reason = dict(form.fields['reason'].choices)[reason]
```

Comment: Django [allows grouped choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#choices). If you have those, this won't work.

Answer (score 172):

See the docs on [Model.get_FOO_display()](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display). So, should be something like :

```
ContactForm.get_reason_display()
```

In a template, use like this:

```
{{ OBJNAME.get_FIELDNAME_display }}
```

Comment: But it's not a model, it's a form.

Comment: Yep. That only holds true for Django models. Forms do not emulate this behavior (though now I'm wishing they did)...

Comment: This is great for models.  Thank you for the hint.  I suppose it still needs to be done differently for forms.

Comment: Had the same problem, but with a `ModelForm`.  
Hence, `{{form.instance.get_FIELDNAME_display}}` worked like charm for me.

Answer (score 29):

This the easiest way to do this: [Model instance reference: Model.get_FOO_display()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display)

You can use this function which will return the display name: `ObjectName.get_FieldName_display()`

Replace `ObjectName` with your class name and `FieldName` with the field of which you need to fetch the display name of.

Comment: *NB* the number of times you mention "model" in your answer (3) and the number of times @webjunkie mentioned it in the question (0).

Comment: `chosen_label = form.instance.get_FOO_display()` is working one

Answer (score 9):

If the form instance is bound, you can use

```
chosen_label = form.instance.get_FOO_display()
```

Comment: This would only work for ModelForm, the question does not mention that.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way I came up with.  There may be an easier way.  I tested it using `python manage.py shell`:

```
>>> cf = ContactForm({'reason': 'feature'})
>>> cf.is_valid()
True
>>> cf.fields['reason'].choices
[('feature', 'A feature')]
>>> for val in cf.fields['reason'].choices:
...     if val[0] == cf.cleaned_data['reason']:
...             print val[1]
...             break
...
A feature
```

Note: This probably isn't very Pythonic, but it demonstrates where the data you need can be found.

Comment: Is there any word on if this sort of thing is part of core now? It's unfathomable that this isn't in the form API yet I have a hard time googling for a better solution.

Answer (score 4):

OK. I know this is **very** old post, but reading it helped me a lot. And I think I have something to add.

The crux of the matter here is that the the model method.

```
ObjectName.get_FieldName_display()
```

does not work for forms.

If you have a form, that is not based on a model and that form has a choice field, how do you get the display value of a given choice.

Here is some code that might help you.

You can use this code to get the display value of a choice field from a posted form.

```
display_of_choice = dict(dateform.fields['fieldnane'].choices)[int(request.POST.get('fieldname'))]
```

the 'int' is there on the basis the choice selection was a integer. If the choice index was a string then you just remove the int(...)

Comment: Any idea how to display the display value of a given choice in a template? I.E. Doesn't seem like `{{form.get_fieldchoice_display}}` works

Comment: There is my answer above, plus there are number of valid answers in subsequent posts. All give options at you disposal, if you want a specific answer, then post your actual code and we can give you specific answer, happy to do so.

Answer (score 3):

You can have your form like this:

```
#forms.py
CHOICES = [('feature', "A feature"), ("order", "An order")]
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
     reason = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES,
                                widget=forms.RadioSelect)
```

Then this would give you what you want:

```
reason = dict(CHOICES)[form.cleaned_data["reason"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Im using @Andrés Torres Marroquín way, and I want share my implementation.

```
GOOD_CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
    ('paper', 'this is paper'),
    ('glass', 'this is glass'),
    ...
)

class Good(models.Model):
    ...
    good_category = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=False)
    ....

class GoodForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Good
        ...

    good_category = forms.ChoiceField(required=True, choices=GOOD_CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    ...


    def clean_good_category(self):
        value = self.cleaned_data.get('good_category')

        return dict(self.fields['good_category'].choices)[value]
```

And the result is `this is paper` instead of `paper`.
Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

confirm that Ardi's and Paul's response are best for forms and not models.  Generalizing Ardi's to any parameter:

```
    class AnyForm(forms.Form):
        def get_field_name_display(self, field_name):
            return dict(self.fields[field_name].choices[self.cleaned_data[field_name]]
```

Or put this method in a separate class, and sub-class it in your form

```
class ChoiceFieldDisplayMixin:
    def get_field_name_display(self, field_name):
        return dict(self.fields[field_name].choices[self.cleaned_data[field_name]]


class AnyCustomForm(forms.Form, ChoiceFieldDisplayMixin):
    choice_field_form = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[...])
```

Now call the same method for any Choice Field:

```
form_instance = AnyCustomForm()
form_instance.is_valid()
form_instance.get_field_name_display('choice_field_form')
```

Comment: now mix it up with a metaclass, and you'll end up with the get_FOO_display thing you can easily use in templates, as you'd do with models...isn't this what everybody wants?

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe @webjunkie is right.

If you're reading from the form from a POST then you would do

```
def contact_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            contact = form.save()
            contact.reason = form.cleaned_data['reason']
            contact.save()
```