# Django: Display Choice Value

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

**models.py:**

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
    )
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    to_be_listed = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=20000, blank=True)
```

**views.py:**

```
def index(request):
    latest_person_list2 = Person.objects.filter(to_be_listed=True)
    return object_list(request, template_name='polls/schol.html',
                       queryset=latest_person_list, paginate_by=5)
```

On the template, when I call `person.gender`, I get `'M'` or `'F'` instead of `'Male'` or `'Female'`.

How to display the value (`'Male'` or `'Female'`) instead of the code (`'M'`/`'F'`)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django print choices value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274243/django-print-choices-value)

Comment: I tried this method, In my template I am using:                         {% for person in object_list %} some html  {{person.get_gender_display() }} html   {% endfor %}                                                        I am getting the following error:                           Exception Value: 
Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 'person.get_gender_display()'

Comment: My Bad, I should not have included '()' after person.get_gender_display. Its working now. Thanks.

Comment: Just a little comment, since gender will only be either M or F(1 character lenght) it has no sense setting the max length of the charfield to `200`. With `max_lenght=1` is enough, will make your site more efficient and you will ensure that you wont have wrong data. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django templates: verbose version of a choice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105638/django-templates-verbose-version-of-a-choice)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the label of a choice in a Django forms ChoiceField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761698/how-to-get-the-label-of-a-choice-in-a-django-forms-choicefield)

Answer (score 700):

It looks like you were on the right track - [`get_FOO_display()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) is most certainly what you want:

In **templates**, you don't include `()` in the name of a method. Do the following:

```
{{ person.get_gender_display }}
```

Comment: This method is priceless. But aside using the method, what's the way to retrieve the value stored in say, {{ i.item.what_to_put_here}} ?

Comment: I don't understand your subquestion.  Is what_to_put_here just a method on item? If so, then your syntax is correct.  This question about the specific situation of having named choices in a Field object.

Comment: Just to note, for anyone using Jinja2 for their templates, you should include the parentheses. `{{ person.get_gender_display() }}`

Comment: Bonus points: what's the best way to do this if you're sending your information via JSON (for instance in a pagination scenario)?  Ideally without the overhead of instantiating the Models one by one and calling get_field_display().

Comment: Gotta love Django, almost 10 years later and the answer is still valid! Thx +1 and drink on me.

Comment: Somehow this doesn't fetch the translated text. Any idea on how to get the translated text if i18 is already implemented on the website?

Comment: @AnoopNair If you still need help with figuring out how to display a translated version of the text you should post a new question.

Comment: how to do this if you only specify choices in the admin/modelform (to not trigger migrations when changing them)

Comment: kind of model hack for me hahaha

Comment: @adamb: I'm from the future: this is 2022. Not a lot has changed since in the world. However, including the parenthesis nowadays result in an error. They no longer are needed.

Answer (score 55):

> For every field that has choices set, the object will have a get_FOO_display() method, where FOO is the name of the field. This method returns the “human-readable” value of the field.

**In Views**

```
person = Person.objects.filter(to_be_listed=True)
context['gender'] = person.get_gender_display()
```

**In Template**

```
{{ person.get_gender_display }}
```

---

[Documentation of get_FOO_display()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display)

Answer (score 0):

I do this by defining constants the following way:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    MALE = 'M'
    FEMALE = 'F'
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        (MALE, 'Male'),
        (FEMALE, 'Female'),
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    to_be_listed = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=20000, blank=True)
```

The M and F values will be stored in the database, while the Male and Female values will display everywhere.

Answer (score -2):

Others have pointed out that a get_FOO_display method is what you need.
I'm using this:

```
def get_type(self):
    return [i[1] for i in Item._meta.get_field('type').choices if i[0] == self.type][0]
```

which iterates over all of the choices that a particular item has until it finds the one that matches the items type

Comment: You can also use `Product.category.field.choices`