# How to show the full name in a ManyToManyField with choices (tuples)?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-templates, django-orm

I have a simple model like this

```
class UserType( models.Model ) :
    def __unicode__( self ) :
        return self.name

    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ( 'ad', 'administrator'    ),
        ( 'mo', 'moderator'        ),
        ( 'vi', 'viewer'           ),
        ( 'pm', 'property manager' ),
        ( 'po', 'property owner'   ),
        ( 'vm', 'vendor manager'   ),
        ( 've', 'vendor'           ),
        ( 'te', 'tenant'           ),
    )

    name = models.CharField( max_length = 2, choices = TYPE_CHOICES )
```

In the `admins.py`, I set `filter_horizontal = ( 'user_types', )` for `UserProfile`, which has a `ManyToManyField` to `UserType`. But in the `UserProfile` admin page, the horizontal filter for M2M only shows the short-name of the tuple:

[image]

Also in a template, I want to show a list of user types a particular user has. So my template code looks like this

```
User type:
<ul>
    {% if user_object.profile.user_types.all %}
        {% for user_type in user_object.profile.user_types.all %}
            <li>{{ user_type|capfirst }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        <li>No user type</li>
    {% endif %}
</ul>
```

And on the template, it displays only the short-name. I know normally I could show it the long-name by doing something like `{{ get_user_type_display }}`, but in this case for M2M, it doesn't work.

So my question is two-fold:

1. How do I display the long-name of a M2M choice/tuple in the admin page?
2. How do I display the long-name in a M2M choice/tuple in a template?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django: Display Choice Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320679/django-display-choice-value)

Comment: That won't work on line 5 of the template code. `<li>{{ get_user_type_display|capfirst }}</li>` will result in an invalid template variable. I can tell because I set `TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID` in `settings.py`. Also what about my first question? I may be wrong, but I think you probably thought "TL;DR" and only read the last part of my question. I already stated that I know about `get_FOO_display`.

Comment: You are right, because you need to use `user_type_name_display` `FOO` is the name of field you want the display for.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I finally got it working with `user_type.get_name_display` :-). Any clue about the admin page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
class UserType( models.Model ) :
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ( 'ad', 'administrator'    ),
        ( 'mo', 'moderator'        ),
        ( 'vi', 'viewer'           ),
        ( 'pm', 'property manager' ),
        ( 'po', 'property owner'   ),
        ( 'vm', 'vendor manager'   ),
        ( 've', 'vendor'           ),
        ( 'te', 'tenant'           ),
        )
    STR_CHOICES = { key : value for (key,value) in TYPE_CHOICES }

    name = models.CharField( max_length = 2, choices = TYPE_CHOICES )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.STR_CHOICES[self.name]
```

Comment: Ooohhh, I had to set it in `__unicode__` (you wrote `__str__` but pretty much the same thing)! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Astevanovic's answer was really helpful for me. There is something I want to add to this.

If you have a model in the field manytomanyfield ...
If you have uploaded all other models from this area in the template ...
You will no longer be calling human readable names `get_` choices `_display`.

It is enough to call this with the `name` which is the `return`.

So now only in the template `{{usertype}}`