# How to render the text of the selected option in template?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a ModelForm that has a widget of type Select

```
 class MyModelForm(ModelForm):
    ...
    widgets = {
        'my_field': Select(
            choices=[('1', 'Choice 1')]
        ),
    }
```

In my view I'm retrieving an already stored model and passing the form as `my_form` to the template:

```
<div>{{ my_form.my_field.value }}</div>
```

As expected, this outputs:

```
 1
```

How can I get the text 'Choice 1' instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: Display Choice Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320679/django-display-choice-value)

Comment: @arogachev is not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not an exact duplicate, [arogachev's duplicate suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320679/django-display-choice-value) did help me realize I should be setting the `choices` attribute in the `Model`'s fields and not the `ModelForm`'s widgets:

```
class MyModel(Model):
    my_field = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=[
        ('1', 'Choice 1')
    ])
```

This way, I can do this:

```
<div>{{ my_form.instance.get_my_field_display }}</div>
```

Which outputs

```
Choice 1
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, to be exact, you need to set `choices` as field argument.