# Why choice field displays keys instead of values in django queryset?

Tags: python, django, choicefield

I have a Choice Field in my models.py

models.py

```
STATUS = (
    ('closed_issue', 'Closed Issue'),
    ('open_ssue', 'Open Issue'),
    ('pending', 'Pending'),
)

class Issue(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=STATUS)
```

views.py

```
def Issues(resuest):
    issues = Issue.objects.all()
```

template

```
{% for issue in issues %}
     {{ issue.status }}
{% endfor %}
```

Output

```
closed_issue 
open_issue
```

---

It displays the keys of the choice field instead of values

I want the values to be displayed in the template. Is there a way to get the values instead of keys?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320679/django-display-choice-value and get_FOO_display

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course there is a way:

`{{ issue.get_status_display }}`

In order to get the values of the `STATUS`es you must use a name convention `get_<field_name>_display()`. More on this [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display).

Comment: Also I have one more doubt What to do if I want the same thing in my view for eg ` for issue in Issues :     print(issue.status)`

Comment: You should do the same, i.e `for issue in issues: print(issue.get_status_display())`.

Comment: @nik_m - If I were to use a `ManyToManyField` pointing to the _key field_ of another model to get my `choice_field`, how do I display the related value of the `ManyToManyField`?