# Obtain the label from my choices in my views.py - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a model where one of the fields is the color assigned.

```
class Gateway(models.Model):
    colors = (
        ('0','Black'), ('1','White'), ('2','Blue'), ('3','Red'),
        ('4','Green'), ('5','Brown'), ('6','Grey'), ('7','Pink'),
        ('8','Purple'), ('9','Orange'), ('10','Yellow'),('11','Darkolive'),
        ('12','Lightpink'),('13','Lightblue'),
    )

    gat_id = models.CharField(max_length=16, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    gat_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    gat_lat = models.FloatField()
    gat_lon = models.FloatField()
    gat_color = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=colors, default='Black')
```

My problem is when I want to obtain the model data in my `views.py`, because I'm doing the following,

```
gateways = Gateway.objects.all()
gateways = loads(serializers.serialize('json', gateways))
```

And this return de `color id` and I prefer the name of the color. Reading some posts I understand I have to use `.choices` but I'm not sure where. Can somebdoy help me please?

Thank you very much

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320679/django-display-choice-value

Answer (score 3):

You Look at [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#choices)
and change

```
gat_color = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=colors, default='Black')
```

To

```
gat_color = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=colors, default='0')
```

#### OR

You can use [IntegerField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#integerfield)

```
class Gateway(models.Model):
    colors = [
        (0,'Black'), (1,'White'), (2,'Blue'), (3,'Red'),
        (4,'Green'), (5,'Brown'), (6,'Grey'), (7,'Pink'),
        (8,'Purple'), (9,'Orange'), (10,'Yellow'),(11,'Darkolive'),
        (12,'Lightpink'),(13,'Lightblue'),
    ]

    gat_id = models.CharField(max_length=16, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    gat_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    gat_lat = models.FloatField()
    gat_lon = models.FloatField()
    gat_color = models.IntegerField(choices=colors, default=0)
```

To Display Value use:

```
gateway = Gateway.objects.all()[0]
gateway.get_gat_color_display()
>>> return 'Black'
```

Comment: What change this?

Comment: i don't understand , could you repeat the question ?

Comment: With this nothing changes, I still obtain the integer and not the label of the color in my view. :)

Comment: you can use `get_<filed Name>_display`