# How to access a specific element from a CHOICES list in Django?

Tags: python, django, list

In my models, I have a choices list, such as:

```
class Graduation(models.Model):
    YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES = [
        ('FR', 'Freshman'),
        ('SO', 'Sophomore'),
        ('JR', 'Junior'),
        ('SR', 'Senior'),
        ('GR', 'Graduate'),
    ]
    student_level = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES)
```

In my views, I want to get the value for a specific element. I have this:

```
search = 'JR'
all_choices = Graduation.YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES
```

My goal is to get `Junior` returned by the system. How can I do that?

I tried:

```
all_choices[search]
```

but that doesn't work. I know I can change the format of my choices list in the models, but in this case my models can not be changed. What is the right way to obtain the label from this list? Do I have to loop through the list and use an `if` statement? That doesn't seem efficient but I am not sure if I have another choice.

Comment: could you share your whole models.py (Graduation class) ?

Comment: Sure, I've added the whole models file

Comment: You might want to use the new `*Choices` classes: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#enumeration-types

Comment: Yes, I normally would, but in this case as I mentioned I can not change the models file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a function like below adn get it

```
 def get_choice(all_choices,search):
      for choice in all_choices:
        if choice[0] == search:
          return choice[1]
 return None    
 get_choice(all_choices,'JR')
```

Comment: Okay, so I have to loop through the whole list. There is no way to do this without a full loop through the list?

Comment: well if you already have the object then you can use https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display

Comment: I don't have the object yet, I just have the "JR" string and want to find the matching item.

Comment: well then you have very limited options. if can change models create a model for your choices and make it a foreignkey. this way you could filter and get it easily

Comment: OK well given the inability to change the model, I'll accept this answer. Looping through the options seems the only way to do this within my constraints. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320679/django-display-choice-value)

Use

```
get_<field_name>_display()
```

Comment: I can't use that in my example, as I don't refer to a specific row in the database.

Comment: Try using TextChoices then instead of this

Answer (score 0):

try this i think using using dictionary will be more efficient than list.the time complexity for dictionary is O(1) and for list it is O(n).

```
search = 'JR'
all_choices = Graduation.YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES
dictionnary = {i[0]:i[1] for i in all_choices}
print(dictionnary[search])
```